# Implementing Keyboard Listener with a Java Applet

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, japplet

I am trying to create a simple game in Java. I am using BlueJ IDE and my code is currently as follows :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;    

public class GameGraphic extends JApplet
{

    // Variable initialization
    private Board board;
    private Dice dice;
    private ArrayList<Player> players; 
    private Player currentPlayer;

    // etc..

    public void init()
    {
        setSize(600,800);

        // Code to initialize game, load images
        // etc..

    }

    // Game method etc..

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        // Drawing game board etc..

        turn++;
        int diceRoll = dice.roll();


        advancePlayer(currentPlayer, steps);
        changeCoins(currentPlayer, diceRoll);

        whoseTurn = (whoseTurn+1)%players.size();

        while(command=="w") {
        }

        try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } 

        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

So right now, it is used a simulation, everything works well and it goes to the next turn each 3 seconds. What I want to do is use keyboard input to go to the next turn. I want it to basically draw the board, wait until a character is typed, if the character is "n" then advance one turn (basically run paint() for one iteration and wait again). 
What is the best way to implement this? I tried using KeyListener but it looks like it does not work with AWT. Thank you so much :)

Comment: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Comment: And because I know some will suggest it, `KeyListener` is not recommend generally and you should look at the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which is designed to solve many of the issues associated with the `KeyListener` API

Comment: Don't call `Thread.sleep` in the `paint` method, this is not how animation should be done, have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Also, don't call `revalidate` (in this case it has no meaning to your program is a waste of time) and `repaint` from within a `paint` method, you're setting yourself up for some series issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with, applets are officially a dead technology and I wouldn't waste time trying to make them work, instead, I'd focus your efforts in other areas of the API.  See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) for more details.

You should never call `Thread.sleep` from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread (or perform any other long running or blocking operations) and especially not from within the context of a paint method.  See [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) for more details.

You should never call any method which could generate a repaint directly or indirectly, painting is for painting and nothing else, doing so could starve the EDT and cause your program to become unresponsive.

A simple solution to doing animation in Swing is to use a Swing `Timer`, which won't block the EDT but which triggers it updates within the content of the EDT, making it safe to update the UI from within.

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

I'd also recommend  you have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) because if you intend to do any kind of custom painting, you should have some understand of how the painting process works.

`KeyListener` is a low level API, which suffers from keyboard focus issues (if the component it's registered to does not have keyboard focus, it won't generate events), instead, you should be using the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API instead.

In the following example, there are two things happening.  The is a `Timer` which is updating a "running time" value and when you press the <kbd>N</kbd> key, it updates a `turn` variable

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GameGraphic  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameGraphic();
    }

    public GameGraphic() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new GamePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {
        private int turn = 0;
        private long runtime;

        public GamePane() {
            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, 0), "next");
            actionMap.put("next", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("...");
                    turn++;
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    runtime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            String text = Integer.toString(turn);
            int x = (width - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((height - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

            text = Long.toString(runtime);
            x = width - fm.stringWidth(text);
            y = height - fm.getHeight() + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java there is an interface for this named **KeyListener** (interface meaning the concept in object-oriented programming)

you add the KeyListener to an object, here is an example:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

here is a website with java game examples http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game4.html (very good...)

Comment: [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Hey MadProgrammer, the example you gave uses JComponent. Does it still hold for a JApplet like the one I have? Because JApplet doesn't seem to accept the interface at all!

Comment: @WassimGr This comes down to a second point, you should avoid overriding paint of top level containers and instead use the applet as a container for a core component (extending from `JComponent` or `JPanel` for example), this way, you don't lock yourself into a single use case (you can add your core component to whatever container you prefer)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am still learning the difference between all of those different components (although they feel the same for me...) but I will try to play with them a bit and figure out which one I would want to use

Comment: @WassimGr As a general rule of thumb, `JPanel` or `JComponent` are preferred if you want to do custom painting, `JApplet` (and `JFrame`) aren't double buffered when they paint so you can end up with annoying flickering. `JPanel` is opaque by default, `JComponent` is not

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that!